# hide loginbox with delay with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this jQuery to display a loginbox and hide it after a successful login. I am trying to delay it to be able to display a message, but it ignores the delay and hide the box immediately.

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     var values = $(this).serialize();

     $("#login-form, #forgot-box, .close, #forgotpass").hide();

     $.ajax({
          url: "login.php",
          type: "post",
          data: values,
          success: function(data){
               setTimeout(function() {$('#log-me-in').fadeOut('slow');}, 4000);          
               $("#logged-in-text").show();
               $("#all-container").load(location.href + '#loginLinks');
          },
          error:function(){
             alert("An error occured!");
          }   
    });
```

});

Comment: use .delay(<your-time>) see the documentation http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$('#log-me-in').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow')` and remove `settimeout`

Comment: This still hides the loginbox right away. It just ignores the delay.

Comment: if I remove `$("#logged-in-text").show();` and `$("#all-container").load(location.href + '#loginLinks');` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#login-form, #forgot-box, .close, #forgotpass").hide();
}, 3000);
```

This will hide the loginbox after 3000 MS

Comment: This will remove the fadeOut effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to first

> $('#log-me-in').fadeOut('slow', function() {
>       // Animation complete.
>     });